# Given a time period, how insert with a timestamp that is not a duplicate and is adjusted if it is?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have items that need to be inserted with epoch timestamps (seconds) that are supposed to be now, but can be adjusted a little within a set time period so they don't trip up the unique constraint for timestamps. For example:

**Time period:** 1469622600 (start) to 1469583000 (end)
**Item 1 timestamp:** 1469622601
**Item 2 timestamp:** 1469622602
**Item 3 timestamp:** 1469622603
**Item 4 timestamp:** 1469582999

*Same Time, Move After*
If I get a new one with timestamp of 1469622603, it should be adjusted to the first available second that isn't used **and** isn't beyond the end: 1469622604.

*Same Time, Move Before*
If I get one that's 1469582999 (so the same as Item #4 **and** only 1 second before the end timestamp), I'd need to move it backward to 1469582998.

Is this possible in MySQL as one query?
Do I need to make many calls?
What's the best way to search for ones that will be duplicates and then find an open time slot?

Comment: This sounds like a really wonky way of trying to enforce uniqueness but not enforce uniqueness. Why not have a compound key based on timestamp and some random fudge factor or UUID?

Comment: @tadman Unfortunately, i can't change the table definition.

Comment: If by "the unique constraint" you mean that you already have a unique index on the column then you could just `try` inserting the row, `catch` the `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` if the value already exists, adjust the timestamp value up or down, and `try` again. Some people object to using exceptions for controlling program flow, but I am not one of those people.

Comment: @GordThompson I'm not objecting to using try...catch, but that could potential result in a lot of trips to the DB if it keeps colliding. That's not a good idea.

Comment: If you're worried about round trips then I suppose you could use a stored procedure to do the insert.

Comment: I just noticed that for your "Time period", `start` is larger than `end` and `end - start` represents a span of -11 hours. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @GordThompson no, meant then to be swapped

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into triggers, it will then be a single set rule at database level - therefore guaranteed accurate with any code / client using it.
AfterInsert looks a good one here. And a single call = the database looks after itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not allowed to use triggers. (Boss has an odd hatred of them)

Comment: Your question states a single query. Therefore by definition a trigger is mandatory without further queries to identify (either before or after) insert to identify and appropriate value.

Comment: Question states 1 query. Therefore a trigger is mandatory without further queries to get appropriate value. 1 query cannot LOCK the table for writing during this process with external code, meaning values could clash if on seperate processes - assuming all code is using the same constraint at design process - no guarantee of this. Your boss should develop a hatred of inefficient buggy code instead of a standard one query solution. To do this in one query means either success or fail (due to key constraint). One query strategy means you cannot try again. You will need multiple querys or trigger